# two simple laplace transformation with simple functions

Tags: complex-numbers, laplace-transform, laplace-expansion

[image: Can someone please help me with these problems]
this is a simple laplace transformation can someone please help me solve this I am stuck

Comment: What have you tried? The "6." suggests that it is homework. People are more willing to answer if you write the steps you have tried already!

Comment: What methods are you studying? Are you to use the definition of the Laplace transform? Have you learned any theorems finding the transforms exponential, sinusoidal or polynomial functions, or certain combinations of those three? If so, you should consult those theorems.

Answer (score 0):

Let's remind the definition of the Laplace transform:
$$
\mathcal L(f)(s) = \int_0^{\infty} f(t) e^{-st} \, dt
$$
So for example, we have with $f(t) = e^{-t} \cos(2t)$ that
$$
\mathcal L(f)(s) = \int_0^{\infty} \cos(2t) e^{-(s+1)t} \, dt = \mathcal L(g)(s+1))
$$
with $g(t) = \cos(2t)$. You can either compute it yourself or lookup a table, but
$$
\mathcal L(t \mapsto \cos(at))(s) = \frac s{s^2+a^2}
$$
so $\mathcal L(g)(s) = \frac{s}{s^2+4}$. It follows that
$$
\mathcal L(f)(s) = \mathcal L(g)(s+1) = \frac{s+1}{(s+1)^2 + 4} = \frac {s+1}{s^2 + 2s + 5}.
$$
Similarly, you expand $(4e^{2t} - 2)^3$ as a polynomial in $e^t$ and rely on tables to compute the Laplace transform of the individual terms, and then rely on the linearity of the Laplace transform.

Hope that helps,